# What mathematical algebra explains sequence of circular shifts on rows and columns of a matrix?

Tags: group-theory, matrices, permutations, foundations, rubiks-cube

Consider the following $3 \times 3$ matrix

$$ \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 4 & 5 & 6 \\ 7 & 8 & 9 \end{bmatrix} $$

Circular shifts can be performed on any row or any column thus:
row-(1/2/3)-(right/left)  and  column-(1/2/3)-(up/dn)

Examples: R1-right transforms [1 2 3] to [3 1 2].
R3-left makes [7 8 9], [8 9 7].
Also: C1-up converts [1 4 7] to [4 7 1].

Now these moves can be performed repeatedly on the initial matrix.
Assume a sequence of moves thus:
R1-r, C1-up, R3-left, C2-dn, R2-r, C3-up

This converts the initial matrix to this matrix (you can work this to confirm):
[4 9 1; 6 7 3; 8 5 2].

Now assume that you know NONE of these moves?

Given simply the 2 matrices: the initial and the final, what method shall help me find the moves that lead from the initial to final, or final to initial. The latter shall be an inverted sequence of each former moves' reverse.

What algebra goes here in?
Please point to any and every resource like group theory, number theory, permutation theory, sequential circuits etc...

This matrix 'jumbling' if you say so, inspired in part from the Rubik's Cube finds some interesting applications in cryptography and data transformation.

I look forward to answers and some future collaboration.

Comment: Hmm. I am not sure, but it is not a "nice" operation. For example, the following matrix has determinant six. $$A=\left[\begin{array}{cc}2&1\\2&4\end{array}\right]$$ Now, rotate it to obtain the matrix $B$ as follows. $$B=\left[\begin{array}{cc}1&2\\2&4\end{array}\right]$$ The matrix $B$ has determinant $0$. Nice matrix becomes nasty matrix...

Comment: Apparently this problem is [regularly reinvented](http://puzzlingiphone.wordpress.com/2008/11/22/toroidal-sliding-block-puzzles/) as a smartphone app.

Answer (score 2):

Permutation theory is all that's needed.

I'll assume that both dimensions of the matrix are at least 2. (If one of the dimensions is $1$, of course only cyclic permutations are possible).

If all the entries are different and both the sides of the matrix have **odd** lengths, then only *even* permutations of the elements are possible, because each of the basic moves is an even permutation. (If there are at least one pair of equal elements, then we can always find an even permutation that looks like any odd one, so in that case all rearrangements of the elements are possible).

If at least one of the lengths are **even**, then every permutation is possible.

In the $2\times 2$ case it is easy to make any desired permutation. The following algorithm works if there are at least 3 columns (and, mutatis mutandis, if there are at least 3 rows):

1. Put the right elements into position in the two first cells of the first row. Let's call these elements $X$ and $Y$. (This is easy enough because at this step we don't care where any of the other elements go in this phase).
2. If the permutation we still need to do at this point is *odd*, then slide the bottom row (if there's an even number of columns) or the last column (if there's an even number of rows) once in your favorite direction. Now the permutation is *even*.
3. Express the desired permutation as a sequence of evenly many swaps of elements that are not $X$ or $Y$ (which are already in position). Perform each swap by doing the following three steps:
4. Let the elements we want to swap be $A$ and $b$. Perform a sequence of moves that place $a$ and $b$ next to each other beneath $X$ and $Y$. Again it it immaterial what happens to element that are not in $\{A,B,X,Y\}$.
5. Do `C2d R2r C2u R1r C2d R2l C2u R1l C2d R2r C2u R2l`. This will exchange $a$ and $b$ with the side effect of also exhanging $x$ and $y$, but leaves everything else unchanged:

   ```
   X Y m m    X q m m    X q m m    X A m m    m X A m    m q A m    m q A m
   A B n n -> A Y n n -> n A Y n -> n B Y n -> n B Y n -> n X Y n -> X Y n n
   p q . .    p B . .    p B . .    p q . .    p q . .    p B . .    p B . .
   p q . .    p q . .    p q . .    p q . .    p q . .    p q . .    p q . .

      m Y A m    Y A m m    Y q m m    Y q m m    Y X m m    Y X m m
   -> X B n n -> X B n n -> X A n n -> n X A n -> n B A n -> B A n n
      p q . .    p q . .    p B . .    p B . .    p q . .    p q . .
      p q . .    p q . .    p q . .    p q . .    p q . .    p q . .
   ```
6. Do the opposite of the moves from step (4).

Since steps (4), (5), (6) are repeated an even number of times, their net effect is to leave $x$ and $y$ where they started out. But that means the desired permutation has been achieved.

Comment: You have taken a 4X4 matrix, and operated on the 2X2 index alone. The end result is the 2X2 sub-matrix got swapped/flipped over wrt the vertical axis i.e. the columns got exchanged. I appreciate the effort, especially since you have shown that a swap, which is a non-Rubik's operation, can be achieved via such shifts only. But, why have you taken a 4X4 matrix with repeated elements AND could you please explain something/point to some reference about even and odd permutations??

Comment: @pratchit: The $4\times4$ in the figure is just an example; the same sequence of moves works for any size from that's at least $2\times2$. I'm not assuming that there are repeated elements -- each of the `m m m`, `n n n`, `p p p`, and `q q q` in the example just stands for _some_ sequence of elements that will be left unchanged by the entire operation. You will notice that each of them moves as a group and is never separated during the entire swap (which is also why you can imagine each of them to be as long or sort as you like).

Comment: @pratchit: Even and odd permutations will be explained in every single introduction or textbook about permutation theory under the sun. An even permutation is one that can be produced by an even number of swaps; an odd permutation is one that can be produced by an odd number of swaps. One of the first things one proves in permutation theory is that an odd number of swaps never results in the same permuation as any even one.

Comment: (Oh, and any introduction to group theory or basic abstract algebra ought to cover the necessary permutation theory. Even most semi-popular works explaining Rubik's Cube would probably do).

Comment: Yeah I got it. Later I looked up even and odd permutations, and came across the cycles and transpositions definitions and theorems etc. The Row and Column operations on a 3X3 matrix are all  even permutations, since they taken even swaps to produce the final result. The question now is given the final destination matrix, can we comment whether this state is really achievable via some moves of this kind (row, column circular shifts i.e.)